# How to store store the value 10^20 in C?

Tags: c, long-long

I want to multiply two numbers of sizes `10^10`, resulting size is `10^20` which is `2^66`.

I want to store that number in a standard datatype in C. I would rather not use "GNU MP Bignum library".

Why does the following C program not hold the number correctly?

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef long long int ull;
int main(){

    ull n1 = 10000000000LL;
    ull n2 = 10000000000LL;

    printf("%llu",n1*n2);
    return 0;
}
```

What would be the best way to hold this number and work with it?

Comment: There unless you have a machine that supports single integers beyond 64 bits (I'm sure they exist, but I don't know of a processor that does), then there's no solution.

Comment: If you don't want to use an existing library, you'll have to roll your own large integer class.

Comment: Unless of course, you are willing to write some inline assembler...

Comment: @MatsPetersson Assembler isn't necessary to implement your own large integer class.

Comment: If your compiler supports `__uint128_t`, it should fit the result of that multiplication.

Comment: @James: Of course not, but in x86-64, it would be simple to do, since a single instruction does 64 x 64 -> 128 bit multiplication.

Comment: @user650521: Would it be possible to explain what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @MatsPetersson 64-bit multiplication wouldn't help much if you wanted to go beyond 128-bit results.  A generic class that can scale to any range would be preferable in my opinion, and for that you don't need any assembler. Assembler could be used for performance reasons, but the class can be implemented in vanilla C++ quite easily.

Comment: @James: Did the OP ask for "arbitrarily large integer multiplication", or "just slightly above 64-bit"? Solving the OP's problem is what we're looking for, right? Not solving some arbitrary problem that just happens to ALSO solve the OP's problem.

Comment: You can represent 10**20 with a Boolean, using true to represent 10**20 and false to represent anything else. This question cannot be usefully answered in its current form. You must specify what other values (such as a range of integers) you want the data type to be able to represent, what operations you want to be able to perform, and any other criteria, such as performance characteristics of the operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store it as two `long long` values. Here's a sketch of a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long long ull;

void multiply( ull a, ull b, ull * lo, ull * hi )
{
  ull ah = a >> 32;
  ull bh = b >> 32;
  ull al = a & 0xFFFFFFFF;
  ull bl = b & 0xFFFFFFFF;

  ull mid = ah * bl + al * bh;
  ull albl = al * bl;

  ull imm = mid + ( albl >> 32 );

  *lo = ( mid << 32 ) + albl;
  *hi = ah * bh + ( imm >> 32 );
}

int main()
{
  ull n1 = 10000000000LL;
  ull n2 = 10000000000LL;

  ull lo, hi;

  multiply( n1, n2, &lo, &hi );

  printf( "result in hex is %llx%016llx\n", hi, lo );
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
result in hex is 56bc75e2d63100000
```

Comment: `a = ah * 2^32 + al`, `b = bh * 2^32 + bl`, `a * b = ( ah * 2^32 + al ) * (bh * 2^32 + bl) = ...` expand the parens yourself and you'll get the idea of the code

Comment: At first I thought you might be missing the carry out of the bottom into the top, but now I see it is `( imm >> 32 )`.

Comment: If you are hard coding `32` and `%016`, why not be consistent &  use `uint64_t`.  If you want `unsigned long long` replace `32` with `sizeof(ull)*8/2` or sizeof(ull)*char_bit/2`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement an arbitrarily large numerical value using a variety of strategies.

I am personally a fan of using a linked list. The idea would be to store every digit in a node. You would need to implement an addition, subtraction, multiplication and division function respectively.

Comment: Would it not be better to use strings?

Comment: Both lists and strings would be prohibitively slow.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, clarified. It's my personal favourite that's why I used it as an example.

Comment: It would be better to use gmp, which is its whole raison d'etre.

Comment: Using gmp is not a good idea. gmp `abort()`s your program if fed large inputs, and has lots of other bad behavior. It's very low-quality software.

Comment: A reasonable approach.  Easy to use in another base like 10.  Order of complexity the same as other approaches.

Comment: I did not intentionally vote down this answer, but Stack Overflow recorded a vote down (misplaced tap), so I made a trivial edit so that Stack Overflow would let me undo the vote.

Answer (score 2):

On a 64 bit architecture a `long long` holds at most 2^63-1.  On 32 bit at most: `2^32 -1`.  If you need bigger numbers than that, then you should re-evaluate what you are doing if there is a better way to solve the problem.

If you need bigger numbers, you'll have to either create your own library or use someone else's library:

Here are two libraries to handle Arbitrary Precision numbers.  The limits of how big a number you can use depend on the amount of disk space, memory, and processing power you have to hold and compute them.

[GMP](http://gmplib.org/) and [MAPM](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~ringx004/mapm-main.html)

If you must roll your own, You could store it in an array of integers.  A 64-bit integer is just two 32-bit integers. A 1024 bit integer could also be seen as thirty two 32-bit integers.  Create a class which holds arrays of integers, stitching them together into any size you need.  The hard part is then to write functions which can add subtract multiply and divide the arrays of integers.